# Where is the ListBox/Spreadsheet Widget for gtk#/Xamarin in designer View?

Tags: xamarin, gtk#

This should be an easy question.  Where is the ListBox/Spreadsheet Widget located for Xamarin/gtk# in designer View?

Answer (score 1):

In GTK, there is a similar concept to what you are describing which is known as a TreeView. More information can be found on the Mono documentation [site](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/widgets/treeview-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

You may want a NodeView, which is a non-hierarchical widget similar to a TreeView as mentioned by cib.